# How to get value from multiple combobox using jQuery

Tags: jquery, combobox

I have multiple combobox with different name. Please see the code below:

```
for($i= 1 ; $i <= 5 ; $i++)
{
?>
    <select class="department" name="department[]" id="<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <option value="">Choose Department & HOD</option>

        <?php
        $qHOD = oci_parse($c1, "SELECT H.HOD_ID, H.HOD, H.DEPARTMENTID_FK, D.DEPARTMENTID, D.DEPARTMENTNAME, D.LOCATIONID_FK FROM WA_GA_TBL_HOD H, WA_GA_TBL_DEPARTMENTS D WHERE H.DEPARTMENTID_FK = D.DEPARTMENTID AND D.LOCATIONID_FK = 'LC0001' ORDER BY D.DEPARTMENTNAME ASC");
        oci_execute($qHOD);
        while($dHOD = oci_fetch_array($qHOD))
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $dHOD['HOD_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $dHOD['DEPARTMENTNAME']; ?> - <?php echo $dHOD['HOD']; ?></option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
<?php
}
?>
```

Now I want to get the value of the combobox.

I'm using this:

```
$(".department").bind("change", function(e)
{
    var department = $(".department").val(); 
    alert(department);
});
```

But I didn't get any value.

How to do the trick?

Comment: Can you include the resulting html rather than the PHP so we can run the js?

Comment: @guradio Tried to read your suggestion URL but no solution there

Comment: and 1 more @guradio I didn't see any duplicate question there. If you carefully read my question, I think You can see different question with your suggestion URL. *I have read your suggestion URL 10 times and got no solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution.

On jQuery I add this function

```
var department = [];
$('.department option:selected').each(function () {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val) {
    department.push(val);
        }
});
```